# How can I retrieve all of the maximum values from a list?

Tags: java, list, collections, max, comparable

I have a class called `Employee` that implements the `Comparable` interface.

Now I have 5 `Employee` objects in my list, each of which has its own `salary` property. I want to find all of the `Employee` objects that have the max salary.

I can get a single object using

```
 Employee employee = Collections.max(employeeList);
```

but that only returns a single `Employee`, while I am trying retrieve an array or list of all of the objects with the same max value. How can I do this?

Comment: You could sort and take all the items that compare to 0 with the largest one.

Comment: By the way, you should probably have a standalone `Comparator` for the salaries. It doesn't generally make sense to call the employees' salary a natural ordering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be efficient, you should iterate through the list and find all the max elements by yourself:

```
List<Employee> result = new ArrayList<>();
Employee currentMax = null;
for (Employee e : list) {
    if (currentMax == null || e.compareTo(currentMax) > 0) {
        currentMax = e;
        result.clear();
        result.add(e);
    }
    else if (currentMax!= null && e.compareTo(currentMax) == 0) {
        result.add(e);
    }
}
```

This solution is O(n), and requires a single pass through the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Collections.sort(list);
Collections.reverse(list);
Set<Employee> highest = new HashSet<Employee>();
Employee max = list.get(0);
for (Employee employee : list) {
    if (e.compareTo(max) < 0) break;
    highest.add(employee);
}
```

I chose a Set because there should be no duplicates.

Comment: You must iterate from the end of the list, not from the beginning.

Comment: @JBNizet yep - left out `reverse()`. Better now?

Comment: Correct, but That makes a whole lot of work just to find the max elements. First sort (O(n log n), then reverse (O(n)), then iterate through the first elements. You could at least sort in descending order from the start: `Collections.sort(Collections.reverseOrder())`

Answer (score -1):

```
Employee max=Collections.max(employeeList);
List <Employee> maxEmployeeList=new ArrayList<Employee>();
maxEmployeeList.add(max);
for(Employee e:employeeList){
  if(e.equals(max)){
   maxEmployeeList.add(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: `equals` --> `compareTo == 0`?

Comment: @SamMarsh exactly. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: @SamMarsh That *should* be the case. There are cases where it's not, and in that case the ordering is said to be "inconsistent with `equals`". See [the docs for `Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) to see what can happen.